# Resolvent Set of Adjoint is Complex Conjugate

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Given a linear operator $A$ from a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ to itself, we define the resolvent set as
$$\rho (A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb C\mid A-\lambda I\text{ is invertible}\}$$
I would like to show that the resolvent set of the adjoint is given by
$$\rho(A^*)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb C\mid A^* -\lambda I\text{ is invertible}\}= \overline{\rho(A)} = \{\lambda\in\mathbb C\mid \bar{\lambda} \in \rho (A)\}$$
Here the bar denotes the complex conjugate. To show this, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
A^* -\lambda I\:\text{ is invertible} \\[1ex]
& \iff (A^*  -\lambda I)^*\:\text{ is invertible} \\[1ex]
& \iff A - \bar{\lambda}I\:\text{ is invertible} \\[1ex]
&\iff \bar{\lambda} \in \rho(A)
\end{align*}$$

Hence $\lambda\in\bar\rho (A)\iff\lambda\in\rho (A^*)$.

Is this solution correct?

I would like to make sure, as the solution someone else gave me seems more complicated (rather needlessly) than this.

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.